# Can I write directly into the color buffer in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

<strike>For some reason I want to write directly some pixels into the screen. For example, is there any function call that close to: `glDrawPixels(int x, int y)`, or is there any way I can get and set the color buffer?</strike>

Hahaha ... it's funny because glDrawPixels is a name I made up, and after reading Ramya's reply I went to the reference and found that they really got a function called `glDrawPixels`, and it is just what I need. How ironical!

Comment: Why? Do you have any problems with glDrawPixels and glReadPixels?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, glDrawPixels does that, but it's slow, to draw pixel data, use textures by drawing a textured quad. If you want to draw individual pixels, that will be a lot slower than drawing bigger textured areas.

Comment: Maybe I'm just being curious, but how come to draw pixels directly onto the buffer slower than to create a texture, apply it to a quad, and display the quad onto the screen?

Comment: Isn't geometric primitives drawing involving matrix operations? And there are texture mapping computation.

Comment: @trVoldemort You have to copy each pixel you draw each call from System RAM to GPU RAM, textures are copied before drawing them.

Comment: If I use display list, could it make it faster?

Comment: Besides, how do I draw textured quads ensuring that every texel is mapped onto one and exactly one pixel?

Comment: @trVoldermor DL won't make it magically faster. You draw a quad the size of your window/screen and use GL_NEAREST as MIN/MAG filter so no filtering is performed.